# how much energy is stored in a car under sun ? (car interior)

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, solar-energy

When a car is under the sun, the interior is hot. This is due to the interior, especially seats, which are black (or a dark color) so that they heat under sun light and restitute this heat to the air. **how much energy is stored in the interior elements ?**

Is the car interior hot because the space is little or hot because elements heat a lot ?

Comment: is this a black car or a white car?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to find the specific heat capacity of all the materials inside the car, which might be difficult to get, but as a  first estimate you can start with the air in the car. It's specific heat at room temperature is about $c=$1000 Joules/(kg-K).  The "stored energy" I assume you are looking for is the amount of energy that would be released by cooling the air to room temperature (20°C). If we assume the heated car is at 40°C, your stored energy would be:
$E=mc(40-20)$
Where $m$ is the mass of air in the car that you would find using the volume and density (at 40°C).  This would be a good exercise for you to do.